# I found this problem when I upload Flutter App in Google play console( "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Service without Chimera impl)

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-console

["java.lang.IllegalStateException: Service without Chimera impl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1NMn.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLDbG.jpg)

How can i solve this problem?

my uses dependesis:
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
gap: ^3.0.1
firebase_core: ^2.24.0
firebase_auth: ^4.15.0
firebase_database: ^10.3.6
fluttertoast: ^8.2.4
fan_carousel_image_slider: ^0.1.2
font_awesome_flutter: ^10.6.0
readmore: ^2.2.0
flutter_circular_text: ^0.3.1
animated_text_kit: ^4.2.2
image_picker: ^1.0.5
firebase_storage: ^11.5.6
flutter_linkify: ^6.0.0
google_sign_in: ^6.2.1
app_settings: ^5.1.1
flutter_local_notifications: ^16.3.0
firebase_messaging: ^14.7.9
pdf: ^3.10.7
path_provider: ^2.1.2
open_file: ^3.3.2
printing: ^5.11.1
http: ^1.1.2
url_launcher: ^6.2.3
google_fonts: ^6.1.0